# Do not display specific map feature with CartoCSS

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, cartocss

I have built an OpenStreetMap tile server following this [guide](https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-18-04-lts/) and everything seems to work fine.

Now I want to customize the look of the generated tiles, and I started with something I tought it was simple: remove mountain peaks from the map.

I was only half succesful however, because I was able to remove the triangular peak marker, but not the peak name.

According to the CartoCSS [documentation](https://cartocss.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language_elements.html#controlling-output-of-symbolizers-and-symbolizer-attributes) you can remove a specific symbolizer from the output using the syntax

```
symbolizer_name: none
```

So I started to hack the `amentity-points.mss` like this:

```
.points {
    //...

    [feature = 'natural_peak'][zoom >= 11] {
      marker: none;
      marker-file: url('symbols/peak.svg');
      marker-fill: @landform-color;
      marker-placement: interior;
      marker-clip: false;
    }

    //..
}

.text-low-zoom[zoom < 10],
.text[zoom >= 10] {
    //..

    [feature = 'natural_peak'][zoom >= 13],
    [feature = 'natural_volcano'][zoom >= 13],
    [feature = 'natural_saddle'][zoom >= 15],
    [feature = 'tourism_viewpoint'][zoom >= 16] {
      text: none;
      text-name: "[name]";
      text-size: @standard-font-size;
      text-wrap-width: @standard-wrap-width;
      text-line-spacing: @standard-line-spacing-size;
      text-fill: darken(@landform-color, 30%);
      [feature = 'natural_volcano'] { text-fill: #d40000; }
      text-dy: 7;
      [feature = 'tourism_viewpoint'] { text-dy: 11; }
      text-face-name: @standard-font;
      text-halo-radius: @standard-halo-radius;
      text-halo-fill: @standard-halo-fill;
      text-placement: interior;
    }

    //..
}
```

As I said, the peak marker does not get rendered, but its name does.

Am I missing something like another rule overriding my settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just keep searching for "peak" [further down the file](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/master/amenity-points.mss#L1653).  The names of peaks, volcanos etc. are handled together.  Remove the part that is looking for "peak" and the names of peaks will no longer appear.

For some features it's a little more complicated - the name display may be handled in a different .mss file to the icon display, but if you search through the .mss files you'll find what you want.

Comment: Are you suggesting should I just comment `[feature = 'natural_peak']`?

Comment: Yes, but be careful commenting things out in CartoCSS .mss or .mml files because it can make the result hard to read or invalid.

Comment: I am still wondering why the `symbolizer_name: none` syntax in some cases works and in others don't